# moving body down page

Tags: html, css

I want to move all the content on my page down.. I have included 'padding-top:50px;' in the body tag, which does move all the content down.. ok good. 
Now I would like to place content in that newly created 50px space. But nothing appears or is cut off because I guess it is out-of-bounds of the page?

I have also made a wrapper div and placed all page content in that and moved it down, but I still get the same effect of not seeing anything in the newly created space. It reacts the same.

Any suggestions?

thanks

```
<style>
#body{
padding-top: 50px;
}

#cookieText{
z-index:10000;
position:absolute;
top:-30px;
left:327px;
width:270px;
font-family:Arial, sans serif;
font-size:9px;
color:#313131;
line-height:12px;
padding:5px 60px 5px 40px;
border-radius: 2px;
background-color:#efeff0;
border: 1px solid #bec2c3;
}
#cookieBtn{
position:absolute;
top:5px;
right:10px;
font-family:Arial, sans serif;
font-size:10px;
color:#fff;
line-height:12px;
padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color:#83878f;
border: 1px solid #7c8089;
cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<div id="cookieText">
By installing blah blah blah
<div id="cookieBtn"><b>Got It!</b></div>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$("#cookieBtn").click(function(){
$("#cookieText").stop().animate({"top": "-100px"}, 200);
});
$("#cookieBtn").click(function(){
$("#body").stop().animate({"top": "-50px"}, 200);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide some code you're currently working with?

Comment: If you want to place content in the top 50px of the page, you probably ought to add a 50px tall element at the beginning of the page instead of padding the `<body>` by 50px.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do? Are you appending content via jQuery or how are you adding the new content?

Comment: A code example would speak more to us than your comments, please provide us with a **[Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Comment: sorry about that.. yes, I am trying to have a message that will disappear along with the 50px space when the user clicks a button. That part I have already figured out.. I just can't seem to see the content in the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a padding to push down the "body" of your page. Instead but another block above the content inside your body.

```
<body>
    <div class="someHeader">fooheader</div>
    <div class="someContent">foocontent</div>
</body>
```

And then in your css specify

```
.someHeader {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: sorry, im using a proprietary cms for my work, and I dont have the ability to add that. It may be the entire reason for my problems. I can get the page to move down using CSS, just not seeing anything I put in the space. thanks for the answer though.

Comment: You can just as well put this within style tags in your HTML code.

Comment: because of my strange situation with the CMS, im trying to add the 'someHeader' that you suggested using some jquery (insertBefore() ) to insert the div before the wrapper that is part of the cms that I cant change.. Im sorry this sounds so confusing.. I think me fighting the cms is the reason for the confusion.

Comment: Well, what kind of cms are you using?

Comment: its a proprietary cms my companies dev team built.. it allows me (a designer) to add CSS and HTML within a child of the body to alter the design. it doesnt allow intimate changes like adding divs directly in the body div unless i use some jquery, which im trying the before() now, to see if that works..

Comment: i may have to kick this issue to my Dev team, I wanted to figure it out on my own like a big boy, but the issues may be something I cant control. thank you for taking time out to address my issue.